# How can I output a die() message without the location information?

Tags: perl, exception

I've got a script that throws an exception via `die`. When I catch the exception I want to output the message without the location information attached.

This script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

eval {
    die "My error message";
};
if($@) {
    print $@;
}
```

outputs
`My error message at d:\src\test.pl line 7.`

I would prefer just to get the output:
`My error message`

Hopefully people don't focus on why I want to do it but if someone is interested then:

The way my script works, it looks for input and dispatches each piece of input to a handler, if it comes across a piece of input that it can't handle then it throws, so all the exceptions are coming from the same piece of code. Hence the location isn't terribly helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add `\n` to your string:

```
die "My error message\n"
```

This is documented in [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html):

> If the last element of LIST does not
>   end in a newline, the current script
>   line number and input line number (if
>   any) are also printed, and a newline
>   is supplied.

Answer (score 20):

I have a chapter on "Error Handling" in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242) that discusses this. Although you can eliminate file and line number merely by ending your message with a new line, you can also [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) with a reference:

```
eval {
    time % 2 ?
        die { 
            message => q(I died!),
            level   => 'really really serious',
            }
        :
        die "I died as a string!\n";
    };

if( ref $@ ) {
    print "Reference message was $@->{message}\n";
    }
else {
    print "$@\n";
    }
```

I tend not to like newlines at the end of error messages, and although I haven't seen your code, it sounds like a situation where I'd want to add extra information to the exception so I can track down what's going on.

You might also consider using one of the many Exception modules on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brian.  I was not aware of being able to die with a reference.  I can see this being very useful.

Answer (score 3):

See the perlfunc entry for [die](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#die) for all the extra info. And end your message with `\n`.